# Reallocating an array's row and columns

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, dynamic-arrays, coredump

I am writing a basic text editor. For now, I just need to write inrow method which adds a row before specified row. If that row isn't empty, shifts the string next row and adds new row. E.g:

```
1:
2:
3:
4: cool
5:

after run:

1:
2:
3:
4:
5: cool
6:
```

Problem is Segmentation fault(core dumped). I couldn't come to find any solution to this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void inrow(int rownum, char **str, int *row);

void main(void){

   int row=24, col=24,i,j;
   char **str; int *input; char *d;
   str =(char**) malloc(row*col);

   for(i=0; i<row; i++)
      *(str+i) = (char*)malloc(col);
   for(i=0; i<row; i++){
    *(*(str+i)+j) = 0;
    }

   *(str+4) = "cool";
   inrow(4, str, &row);
   dsply(&row, str);


}

//prints array
void dsply(int *rownum, char **str){

   int i;
   for(i=0; i<*rownum; i++)
      printf("%d: %s\n", (i+1) ,*(str+i));

}

void inrow(int rownum, char **str, int *row){

   char *temp;
   str = realloc(str,((*row)+1));
   *temp = **(str + *row);
   *(*(str + *row)) = 0;
   *(str+(*row+1))= temp;

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you get a crash like this, make sure the program is built with debug information (the `-g` flag to GCC) and then run the program in a debugger. The debugger will stop when the crash happens.

Comment: Also, you're allocating 576 bytes (`24 * 24`) for `str`, when you only need 96 or 192 (`24 * sizeof(char *)`) bytes. It would also be easier to understand (even for yourself maybe) if you use array-indexing syntax when dereferencing `str`. Like `str[i] = malloc(...)` or `str[i][j]`.

Comment: The array will expand. For now its size is specified to test functions.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're improperly `malloc`ing memory for `str`:

   ```
   str =(char**) malloc(row*col);

   for(i=0; i<row; i++)
       *(str+i) = (char*)malloc(col);
   ```

   It should be done like this:

   ```
   str = malloc(row * sizeof(*str));
   for(int r = 0; r < row; r++)
       str[r] = malloc(col);
   ```
2. You're using `j` before initializing it:

   ```
   int row=24, col=24,i,j;

   ...

   for(i=0; i<row; i++){
       *(*(str+i)+j) = 0;
   }
   ```
3. You're improperly copying a string to `str`:

   ```
   *(str+4) = "cool";
   ```

   It should be done like this:

   ```
   strncpy(*(str + 4), "cool", col);
   ```
4. It's not necessary to make `rownum` a pointer here...

   ```
   void dsply(int *rownum, char **str){
       ...
   }
   ```

   ...nor `row` a pointer here...

   ```
   void inrow(int rownum, char **str, int *row){
       ...
   }
   ```
5. The following line is incorrect:

   ```
   str = realloc(str,((*row)+1));
   ```

   Perhaps what you're intending is this:

   ```
   str[rownum] = realloc(str[rownum],((*row)+1));
   ```

Comment: 4. I used *row for changing array's size. Inrow function adds one more row and I'll need to access that line.

5. With that, I tried to add on more row to 2D-Array's rows. Again, I'll need to change row number to access that last row.